# Is the movement satisfy quantium Hamilton-Jacobi equation resonable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

If inserting wavefunction $\psi(x,t)=\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}\exp^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S(x,t)}$ into Schrodinger equation,it could be derived two equations:

$\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{1}{m}\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{x_i}}\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{x_i}}+V(x,t)+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\nabla^2\sqrt{\rho}}{\sqrt{\rho}}=0$

$\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}}+div\ ({\rho}\frac{\nabla{S}}{m})=0$

According to Peter Holland's paper:[Computing the wavefunction from trajectories: particle and wave pictures in quantum mechanics and their relation](http://xxx.lanl.gov/pdf/quant-ph/0405145v1),
the two equation had describe the movement of quantum fluid,

the trajectory start from initial position $a$ was denoted as $x(a,t)$ and $x(a,0)=a$,

initial velocity of the trajectory $m\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}}(a,0)=\frac{\partial{S}}
{\partial{x}}(x(a,0),0)$,

the trajectory obey the law : $m\frac{\partial^2{x}}{\partial{t}^2}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(V(x,t)+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\nabla^2\sqrt{\rho}}{\sqrt{\rho}})$,
considering the condition:$\hbar \rightarrow 0$,$m\frac{\partial^2{x}}{\partial{t}^2}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}V(x,t)$,

The density obey the law $\rho(x(a,t),t)=J^{-1}(a,t)\rho(a,0)$
$J(a,t)=\frac{1}{6}\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{mnl}\frac{\partial{x_i}}{\partial{a_m}}\frac{\partial{x_j}}{\partial{a_n}}\frac{\partial{x_k}}{\partial{a_l}}$

The description of my question :

If the trajectory of two different initial position concide at time $t_0$,as a result,
$x(a_1,t_0)=x(a_2,t_0)$ , $S(x(a_1,t_0),t_0)=S(x(a_2,t_0),t_0)$.
**Because $S$ is the function of $x$ and $t$**, $\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}}(a_1,t_0)=\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}}(a_2,t_0)$
$=\frac{1}{m}\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{x}}(x(a_1,t_0),t_0)=\frac{1}{m}\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{x}}(x(a_2,t_0),t_0)$
$m\frac{\partial^2{x}}{\partial{t}^2}(a_1,t_0)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}V(x(a_1,t_0),t_0)$
$=m\frac{\partial^2{x}}{\partial{t}^2}(a_2,t_0)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}V(x(a_2,t_0),t_0)$
So,$x(a_1,t)=x(a_2,t)\ if\ t > t_0$
$\rho(x(a_1,t),t)$
$=J^{-1}(a_1,t)\rho(a_1,0)+J^{-1}(a_2,t)\rho(a_2,0),$
$if\ t > t_0$

I want to calculate quantum fluid evolvation with time, my method is assigning the initial density and velocity of the discrete small units of the fluid,numerical calculation with time added step by step.

If I arbitrarily assign initial velocity and density,it could not be maked sure that $S(x(a_1,t_0),t_0)=S(x(a_2,t_0),t_0)$ when two trajectory starting from $a_1$ and $a_2$ concide as the scheme required.How to make sure this?

As the scheme describe,if more and more trajectories concide together,it seems the fluids converge to only one point at the end,I feel confused about this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is. In particular, the only sentence that ends with a question mark is not actually a question. Please make it clear *what exactly you want to know*, and include all relevant information into your question so that it can be understood without reading the paper you refer to.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_equations

Comment: Only because $x(a_1,t_0) = x(a_2,t_0)$ doesn't mean that $x(a_1, t) = x(a_2, t)$ for all $t > t_0$. To achieve the identity $x(a_1, t) = x(a_2, t)$ for all $t > t_0$ it is necessary and sufficient to have that $x(a_1,t_0) = x(a_2,t_0)$  and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(a_1,t_0) =  \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(a_2,t_0) $. However, only because $S(x(a_1,t_0),t_0) = S(x(a_2,t_0), t_0)$ doesn't mean that $m \, \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(a_1,t_0) = \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}(x(a_1,t_0),t_0) =  \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}(x(a_1,t_0),t_0) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(a_2,t_0) $.

Comment: @Futurologist It seems you could help me with this.Why it does not mean the same velocity,I think $\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{x}}$ could be determined only by $x$ and $t$ , $x(a_1,t_0)=x(a_2,t_0)$ is  sufficient to make sure  $\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{x}}(x(a_1,t_0),t_0)=\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{x}}(x(a_2,t_0),t_0)$.Maybe I am not right?Thanks very much.

Comment: The solution $S(x,t)$ actually depends on parameters $y$ of the same dimension as $x$, so in fact you have $S(x, y, t)$. That's why you may have non-coinciding  derivatives with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, ok, I think I get what you are asking. First of all what is your definition of $x=x(a,t)$? In general, there should be some initial value problem. What is it?

You are given the system of PDEs
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} \, + \, \frac{1}{2m} \,\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \cdot  \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}\right) \, + \, V(x,t) \, + \, \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho}} \, \frac{\partial^2 \sqrt{\rho}}{\partial  x^2} = 0\\ 
&\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} \, + \, \frac{1}{m} \, \text{div}\left(\rho \, \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}\right) = 0
\end{align}
where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is the gradient with respect to the variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (not including the time variable $t\,$) and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ is the Laplace operator with respect only to $x$ and not including $t$.

Furthermore, define the Hamiltonian 
$$H(x, p, t) =  \frac{1}{2m} \,p^2 \, + \, V(x,t) \, + \, \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}} \, \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial  x^2}\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}$$
Then this Hamiltonain leads to the system of ODEs
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} (x,p,t)\\
\frac{dp}{dt} &= - \,\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} (x,p,t)
\end{align} which looks like
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{1}{m}\, p\\
\frac{dp}{dt} &= - \,\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(\, V(x,t) \, + \, \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}} \, \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial  x^2}\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}\, \right)
\end{align} or equivalently as a second-order ODEs
\begin{align}
m \, \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} &= - \,\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(\, V(x,t) \, + \, \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}} \, \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial  x^2}\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}\, \right)
\end{align} The proper initial value problem looks like this
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{1}{m}\, p\\
\frac{dp}{dt} &= - \,\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(\, V(x,t)
\, + \, \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}} \, \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial  x^2}\sqrt{\rho(x,t)}\, \right)\\
& \,\, x(t_0) = x_0\\
& \,\, p(t_0) = p_0
\end{align}
Then, the corresponding solutions looks like this
$$x(t) \, = \, x\big(\, t \, ; \, t_0, x_0, p_0 \, \big)$$ so that $x(t_0) \, = \, x\big(\, t_0 \, ; \, t_0, x_0, p_0 \, \big) = x_0$ and $\, m \, \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \big(\, t_0 \, ; \, t_0, x_0, p_0 \, \big)  = p_0$

Now, let us take two solutions $ x\big(\, t \, ; \, t_1, x_1, p_1 \, \big)$ and $ x\big(\, t \, ; \, t_2, x_2, p_2 \, \big)$ with $t_1 \leq t_2$ and assume that for some $t=t_0$
$$ x\big(\, t_0 \, ; \, t_1, x_1, p_1 \, \big) = x\big(\, t_0 \, ; \, t_2, x_2, p_2 \, \big) \,\, \text{ and } \,\,  \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \big(\, t_0 \, ; \, t_1, x_1, p_1 \, \big) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \big(\, t_0 \, ; \, t_2, x_2, p_2 \, \big)$$    Then by the existence and uniqueness theorem $$ x\big(\, t \, ; \, t_1, x_1, p_1 \, \big) = x\big(\, t \, ; \, t_2, x_2, p_2 \, \big)$$ for all $t$  where the solutions exist, for $t$ before and after $t_0$. Therefore, there exists $t_{21}$ such that 
$$ x\big(\, t_{21} \, ; \, t_1, x_1, p_1 \, \big) = x\big(\, t_2 \, ; \, t_2, x_2, p_2 \, \big) = x_2 \,\,$$  and $$ \,\, \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \big(\, t_{21} \, ; \, t_1, x_1, p_1 \, \big) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \big(\, t_2 \, ; \, t_2, x_2, p_2 \, \big) = p_2$$   In other words the two solutions $ x\big(\, t \, ; \, t_1, x_1, p_1 \, \big)$ and $x\big(\, t \, ; \, t_2, x_2, p_2 \, \big)$ trace exactly the same curve and they were never different to begin with. They were always the same solution. Plus there is a link between the parameters with index $1$ and $2$ given by $t_{21}$ (see above). Therefore, for arbitrary choices of positions and velocities **at the same moment of time** no merging can occur unless these initial conditions are equal.

Comment: Thanks,the answer is helpful.Now there is another question:If there is a case : $x(t_0;t_1,x_1,p_1)=x(t_0;t_1,x_2,p_2)$ and $\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}}(t_0;t_1,x_1,p_1)\neq\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}}(t_0;t_1,x_2,p_2)$, this case should not happen if the statistic movement satisfy hamilton jaccobi equation.So the initial velocity still difficult to determined. Maybe classic fluid computation method have deal with this problem.                  And the density at the boundary may be zero,potential could not be calculated. Some ideas?